# ajax and portable OSes

Tags: php, ajax

Well, i have an select list in my php page and i want to refresh only that with new data from my database.Idone it using ajax but on android or other mobiles OSes this messes up the layout.Is there a problem with protable OSes and ajax?Can you give me any hints to solve this problem?

Edited

```
/*function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      var sel1 = document.getElementById("select1");
      var selectedI = sel1.selectedIndex;

      var i=0;
      var excode = excur[selectedI];
      var val = sel1.options[selectedI];

      excursioncode=excode;
      excindex = selectedI;
      val.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

      //setTimeout("loadXMLDoc();",10000);
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST","<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>ajaxphp/ajax_get_seats.php?excode="+excursioncode+"&date="+selected_date,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    tm=setTimeout("loadXMLDoc();",timeoutPeriod);
}
*/
```

This is some code that is doing the job.On a regular pc is working but on a mobile browser brings up problems.Anyu ideas

Comment: Not with what little information you give: we would need to see some code and an exact description of the problem.

Comment: Can you track your request on server? I mean can your server receive your request from mobile or such things?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem were with the AJAX, it would not be causing layout issues. Instead the problem is most likely with your implementation of using the data retrieved by AJAX. However, I can't provide any more insights because I have no clue what you're working on and have never experienced such a problem.